# Redirect by url webapp java

Tags: java, nginx, jakarta-ee, web-applications, tomcat8

My configuration is the following:
I have an Nginx, Tomcat 8 and a Java webapp.
I set up the URL coop.example.com and mapa.example.com to be redirected from Nginx to Tomcat to open the same webapp and this is working as expected.

The problem is that with mapa.example.com must open as default the map page, but I have to do using the following: mapa.example.com/o/map
It is working but not always.

What I would like to achieve is that mapa.example.com redirect directly to the map page without typing /o/map after the URL.

I know its a configuration related with Nginx and/or Tomcat 8, but I cannot find any solution yet.

Could you kindly please share some information to achieve this?
Thank you

What I tried is just experimenting searching in different websites but nothing useful found.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect-java.lang.String-

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't see how this comment can help me. It is about sendRedirect, but what I'm trying to do is something related with rewrite rules in nginx or an specific configuration in Tomcat.
Maybe could be helpful if you can explain a bit more how can sendRedirect help me in this situation. Thank you

Comment: And why wouldn't you do the redirect directly from your Java code, so that it doesn't depend on external configuration, on your specific reverse proxy, on your specific application server? That's what sendRedirect allows doing: send a redirect, to redirect (for example), from "/" to "/o/map".

Comment: Well. I think that redirections depending on the domain where webapp is called should be defined outside the code in order to avoid setting an specific domain name hardcoded in a condition. I think that a best approach is to define in nginx or tomcat to allow using any domain or subdomain name without having to redeploy the webapp if you need to change it for any reason. I cannot find a solution yet so maybe I will do the redirection in java code until I find a better solution. Thank you anyway for your option and point of view.